# Is it possible to alter the lookup behavior behind a quickfilter in NAV '13 R2?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

Perhaps this is simply a matter of not completely understanding the Lookup Triggers on tables and pages...

When we perform an item lookup from the quickfilter box on the Item List page, I want to take the input and modify it with certain wildcards like so:

```
NewLookup := CONVERTSTR(OriginalLookup, '-', '*');
NewLookup := OriginalLookup + '|' + NewLookup;
```

... From what I can tell so far, the OnLookup triggers don't fire when performing a quickfilter... at least, I've put code in the onlookup triggers for both the table and the page, without actually performing a lookup action in either case, and the quickfilter will still return results which, so far as I understand, shouldn't happen if I haven't handled all aspects of the lookup myself.

So:

1. Is it possible to modify the behavior of the lookup behind a quickfilter in C/AL?
2. If so, where do I do that? Am I just using the OnLookup trigger wrong and it's just a matter of getting it right, or do I have to go somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Quick Filter in Nav is that edit box on the right side of the page with "Type to filter" inside. It doesn't have any lookups. It accepts only plain text values or some 'macro' filters as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh879085(v=nav.71).aspx).

1. Unfortunately, it is impossible to modify behavior of filter lookups in RTC as it has been in the classic client. Role-tailored client just doesn't invoke C/AL triggers.
2. You are using OnLookup trigger correctly, but it is only called when you click on lookup button in the page field, not in the filters tab.

After you build your filter value. you can apply this filter
SETFILTER(LookupField,NewLookup);
And it will be displayed in the 'Advanced filters' pane, still lookup from this field only takes into account the field's TableRelation property, OnLookup trigger is ignored.

Comment: OK, this gets me part way there... where am I writing the `SETFILTER(LookupField,NewLookup);` code?  I'm OK with it being in the advanced filters pane and the limitations of it using the field's TableRelation property.

Comment: When you filter data using advanced filters pane, input text is being processed by functions Make*Filter (which lead to codeunit 41 TextManagement). 

You may try to edit these functions to get what you want. The main problem is that all you have is a Text variable, there is no information about source table or page.

There is a good guide on this here: http://www.olofsimren.com/custom-filter-formula-in-dynamics-nav-2013/